# Starting a java virtual machine with -Xms8M parameter fails in .NET Compact Framework (C#)

Tags: c#, java, compact-framework

I'm looking for a solution for about 1 1/2 days now and just can't get to the point. I tried to start a *.lnk file in PocketPC 2003 out of our C# application. This *.lnk file contains a link to evm.exe which is a JVM for PocketPC. Argument passed is (besides others) -Xms8M which tells the JVM to reserve at least 8MB of memory.

If directly started from Windows Explorer there's no problem.

Now I created a process in C# pointing to the *.lnk file. When I try to start it the JVM console opens and brings up one of two errors: "EVM execution history too large" or "failed to initialize heap (Phase 1)" (or something like that).

If I delete the mentioned parameter the application comes up with no problem.

Because of this behaviour I assume that there is too few memory assigned to the newly created process. Is this realistic? And if: is there a way to assign more memory to the newly created process? Or am I completely wrong and have to go some other way (if any available)?

**Edit:**
--CodeSnippet--
`this.myStartProcess = new Process { StartInfo = { FileName = appName },EnableRaisingEvents = true };`
`this.myStartProcess.Start()`
--CodeSnippet--

**Edit 2:**
After doing some more research it turned out that the real problem is that there are very limited resources available, eaten up by my launcher application (which is about 1.8 MB in total after starting) over time.
To improve things I started to study how the garbage collector works in Windows Mobile and so used two techniques to bring up the virtual machine.
First one is to reduce the memory taken by my own application by sending it to the background (`SendToBack()` method of the form) and waiting for the garbage collector to finish (`GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()`).
After that I'm looking for 9 MB of free space in program memory before trying to bring the VM up. If there isn't enough space I try to shift the needed memory from storage memory to program memory.
This two techniques improved things a lot!

There's still a problem to my launcher application. The allocated bytes (strings and boxed objects to be concrete) increase over time when my launcher application is in front... It's about 30 kb in 10 minutes. After 24 hours the device will be rebooted automatically. At the moment I assume the launcher will be in front for about 10 minutes total during that period. Nevertheless it's not good to have memory leaks. Anyone got an idea how to chase this down?

Thanks in advance
Best regards
Marcel

Comment: Can you clarify if you are running the process inside the process, or if you are starting a new process? this make a real difference.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you have two reasons for which this could happen:

- The default value provided to MinWorkingSet and MaxWorkingSet Properties are not satisfactory for your requirements. From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.maxworkingset.aspx

> The working set of a process is the set of memory pages currently
>   visible to the process in physical RAM memory. These pages are
>   resident and available for an application to use without triggering a
>   page fault.
>
> The working set includes both shared and private data. The shared data
>   includes the pages that contain all the instructions that your
>   application executes, including the pages in your .dll files and the
>   system.dll files. As the working set size increases, memory demand
>   increases.
>
> A process has minimum and maximum working set sizes. Each time a
>   process resource is created, the system reserves an amount of memory
>   equal to the minimum working set size for the process. The virtual
>   memory manager attempts to keep at least the minimum amount of memory
>   resident when the process is active, but it never keeps more than the
>   maximum size.
>
> The system sets the default working set sizes. You can modify these
>   sizes using the MaxWorkingSet and MinWorkingSet members. However,
>   setting these values does not guarantee that the memory will be
>   reserved or resident.

- It is effectively impossible to reserve the memory you are requiring for the JVM on your machine, because the way the OS manages memory ( which I would find really suprising because every modern os has virtual memory support)

Comment: This doesn't apply to compact framework. The MaxWorkingSet and MinWorkingSet members aren't available there.